# Android webview dropdown menu does not work on Android 4.x devices

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview, android-tabhost

I have a problem with one of my `WebView` on Android 4.x devices.

Android app has a **Tabhost** which contains **Fragments**. One of the fragments contains a webview. The displayed page has a dropdown menu like this:

```
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
    <option value="1">Testname 1</option>
    <option value="2">Testname 2</option>
    <option value="3">Testname 3</option>
</select>
```

Now when I open my app with a Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.1 (or any other Android device I could get my hands on) I can select "Testname 1", then "Testname 2" and so on.

On the Galaxy Nexus (confirmed on different devices running Android 4.1.1, 4.1.2 and 4.2) when I try to select something the UI just blocks. After I switch to another tab and back to the webview tab suddenly the UI finally changes to the previously selected item.

Any idea what is causing this or how I can fix this for the Galaxy Nexus?

**Important update:**
I could track this down to the `Tabhost`. When the `webview` is in the `tabhost` it does not work, when it is not it works. This might be related to [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2516).

Comment: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquerymobile-1-0-does-not-support-android-4-0-ice-cream-sandwich

Comment: Seems unrelated, as my minimal example only contains the code above (+``<html><body>`` and so on) and no jquery anymore at all

Comment: Not sure if this will make a difference but maybe its worth a shot use @+id/mySelect for the id

Comment: @Raanan No solution yet, except replacing the TabHost :(

Comment: Are you using Tabhost from the support library?

Comment: @Tim Have you got any new leads for this issue ? I have exactly the same on and I've been struggling with it for 2-3days now !

Comment: Actually I still do not have a fix for this. However Raanan build a workaround for this. Not entirely sure how the solution was, but basically inject javascript that catches the touch event, and instead of showing the list in the browser show a native Element with your options. After a selection inject javascript that changes the elements accordingly. For a more detailed description you will have to ask Raanan.

Comment: Thank you very much @Tim, but I think I will rather replace my old TabHost by a ActionBar !

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do more with ActionBar than you can with just a TabHost. Including Tabs. [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) will allow you to implement the ActionBar in older versions minSdk = 4. A majority of the User Experience developers I have worked with think that Tabs are kind of passe although the do provide a familiar UI to users, but who am I to blow against the wind? The ActionBar provides a very Android specific look and clean feel to the UI. [link](http://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-android-ui-design-patterns.pdf) is the documentation on Google's recommended UI patterns from that conference. [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1ZBjlCRfz0) is the YouTube video discussing the UI patterns from the conference. Following these recommendations can provide a better review of your application and more sophisticated UI look for it. I am not sure what your needs are but if you are going to do something, might as well do it right? If you need some more help please let me know. I can get you examples on using the ActionBar. [ActionBar link](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) can give you some better reasons that I can why it is a good choice for the UI.

Are you implementing your Fragments correctly? [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) is the documentation on using  them. If you are using dynamic fragments instead of fixed fragments implemented in the layout one trick that I found when writing across applications is to call the .clearBackStack(); when I am having funny issues and it seems to fix a lot of problems.

Comment: Hi Sean, the link will not enable me to use the ActionBar in previous versions of Android, see ActionBarSherlock for that for instance. However, *another* answer of you stating that I should use the ActionBar instead will still not solve the problem at hand. And I already stated that I cannot use it because I cannot implement what I have to implement with it (and yes, I have read the docs and no, I cannot go into the details right now). Now I could implement everything manually without the TabHost (that *does* work), the question is still, why is it not working with the TabHost?

Answer (score 0):

TabHost in ICS? Are you using the compatibility package? Proper design would be to use the ActionBar to implement Tabs if you are working in basically 3.1+.

Comment: There are still reasons to use the ``TabHost`` instead of the ``ActionBar``, one being compatibility with Android 2.3, others being e.g. that I cannot do everything with the ``ActionBar`` that I can do with the ``TabHost``.

Comment: [use this for any extra issues with the ActionBar](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) it has helped me in the past, you can import the libraries and see the code. If you are more specific I can probably post an example for you. In the link you posted inside your question there is a workaround at the bottom of the article. Let me know what I can do to help. [link](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments) is the link to the fragments examples with Sherlock library. Seriously let me know if you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this custom class in your XML layout instead of the normal TabHost:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class TabHostFix extends TabHost
{
    public TabHostFix(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public TabHostFix(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchModeChanged(boolean isInTouchMode)
    {
        //do not call through to base class, do nothing
        //this is a fix for tabhost stealing focus from textboxes
    }
}
```

Reference the custom class in your XML layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.test.TabHostFix xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</com.example.test.TabHostFix>
```

EDIT:
As an alternative solution, you may be able replace TabHost completely by using the ViewPager from the support library and a custom View Pager indicator that mimics tabs.  I've never tried this before, but I have read that there are good free 3rd party view pager indicators [here](http://viewpagerindicator.com/).

Comment: Also, I would agree that using ActionBar Tabs would be ideal -- but there are some rare cases where TabHost is more flexible, such as if you want to force stacked tabs no matter the device/orientation, etc.

If the only reason you are not using ActionBar Tabs is because of backwards compatibility then I would highly recommend the ActionBarSherlock library.  It is easy to use and doesn't take much time to setup.

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work (still the same behaviour as before) :(

Comment: very interesting...  i just tested with the emulator running 4.1 and can confirm the same results as you.  The code I posted above fixes the tabhost from stealing focus on textboxes, but does NOT correct the strange behavior with drop downs in a webview.

Answer (score 0):

After Selecting the select, the List item data might change but we can't see the change. for this we need to explicitly refresh the select component. Hope this might solve the problem.

`$("select#HeightUnit option[value='cm']").attr("selected", "selected");
$('select').selectmenu('refresh');`

Comment: Can you give me some more context how this is supposed to solve the problem and not make my UI block anymore?

Comment: Html refresh is the most important one. When give the Select as like previously.The value will be set. When we clicked on it, the Webview make it open as the Drop down. but when we change the value will be changed but in the webview it might not refresh. So we need to explicitly refresh/ going to another tab and comes to webview tab will any way refresh the screen.  In your case $('#select#mySelect').attr('selected','selected'); $('select').selectmenu('refresh');. will refresh that select component alone in the webview

Comment: So, this might refresh the select menu, right? BUT: The whole UI would still be blocked. I would still not be able to select anything else, other UI elements and so on.

Comment: Can you run the application using weinre and check whether any other javascript errors are there.

Comment: What Javascript errors? I mean, the code above is pretty much ALL that there is. There is no Javascript that runs.

Answer (score -2):

```
> i think u must add the API version on your activity cause some UI cannot compatible on >android API 8. so check the API SDK like this.

>@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
>if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
>{
>// condisition
>}
```